# Why are the words not vertically centered

Tags: html, css

Here is a simple HTML file with inline css:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <style type="text/css"> 
    body {
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-right: 500px;
        margin-left: 500px;
    } 
    .events { 
        font-size: 200%;  
        vertical-align:middle;
        text-align:left;
        margin-left:20px;  
    } 
    .sections{ 
        font-size: 100%;  
        vertical-align:middle;
        text-align:right;
        margin-right:20px; 
    }

    #divA {
        background-color: #BB1919;
        color:white;
        height:60px;
        font-family: Arial; 
        font-weight:bold; 
        } 
    </style> 
</head> 
<body>  
    <div id="divA"><div class="events">EVENTS</div>
      <div  class="sections">Sections</div> 
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

The large red rectangle is correct. BUT why are the words EVENTS and Sections not vertically centered? It seems quite simple and yet it doesn't look correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vertical-align:middle;` works only when parent has `display:table` and children `display:table-cell`

Take a look:

```css
  body {
   margin-top: 20px;
   margin-right: 100px;
   margin-left: 100px;
  } 
  .events { 
   font-size: 200%;  
   vertical-align:middle;
   text-align:left;
   margin-left:20px;  
            display:table-cell;
  } 
  .sections{ 
   font-size: 100%;  
   vertical-align:middle;
   text-align:right;
   margin-right:20px; 
            display:table-cell;
  }

  #divA {
   background-color: #BB1919;
   color:white;
   height:60px;
            width:100%;
   font-family: Arial; 
   font-weight:bold; 
            display:table;
   }
```

```html
   <!doctype html>
    <html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
 </head> 
 <body>  
  <div id="divA"><div class="events">EVENTS</div>
          <div  class="sections">Sections</div> 
  </div> 
 </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here is how you do it :

```css
#divA {
  display:block;
  background: #BB1919;
  color:white;
  height:100px;
  padding:20px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
} 
.divA {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.events,
.sections { 
  display:table-cell;
  font-size: 20px;  
  vertical-align:middle;
  
} 

.divB {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background:#f5f5f5;
  padding:20px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<h2>If you need Outer Div</h2>
<div id="divA">
<div class="divA">  
  <div class="events">EVENTS</div>
  <div class="sections">SECTIONS</div> 
</div>  
</div> 

<h2>If you dont</h2>
<div class="divB">  
  <div class="events">EVENTS</div>
  <div class="sections">SECTIONS</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The css property `vertical-align` will align elements on the same line. As you can see in the example below, three divs are centered through the middle because of that property. Vertical-align will not center text inside an element, though.

One way to achieve that without tables is to set the line height property to the same height value of the container. In the example below, the container is 60px tall and so is the text line.  This method works if the text is contained in *one line only*.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.lg {
  height: 60px;
}

.sm{
  height:40px;
}

.centerTxt{
  line-height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sm">
Small
</div>
<div class="lg">
Large
</div>
<div class="lg centerTxt">
Large centered text
</div>
```